# How to show Calendar event response options in Calendar Message with Graph API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm attempting to replicate the response options to a Calendar meeting invite email message that shows up in Outlook 365 using the Graph API.  The email message correctly returns but with a limited body.content.  There doesn't appear to be a good Calendar or Mail API call to produce that html and give the user an option to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Graph is a just the API. It will return the data you're looking for but it is up to your application to provide the user experience and composing the reply.

Comment: Yea, I know. Was just hoping there was some boilerplate html it would generate because it's an event message